# Need help on running a ASP.Net project with .ascx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, user-controls

For the past two days I am struggling a lot while I am trying to compile and run an existing ASP.net project where user controls are used. The problem I am facing are as below

1. While I am trying to compile the project the .ascx file is getting error that could not load type which is defined in the inherit tag section. In the inherit section the like this Inherits="UserInfoBoxControl" in my project before the usercontrol name another namespace is added which I have not find any where in the project. But I have the .ascx code files with me.To overcome this what I can do?
2. Next problem is that while compiling the project I am getting some errors in .ascx files.But the strange issue is that it is taking the code files for the usercontrol from a backup folder of my project instead of the project main folder.What is the configuratin I can change in my project so that it will take the code files for the usercontrol from my project main folder.

The code for the .ascx file is

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ViewClinic.ascx.cs" Inherits="Tree.Templates.DynamicContent.Vpo.UserControls.ViewClinic" %>


<link type="text/css" href='<%=ResolveUrl("../Styles/StyleSheetVpo1.css")%>' rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveUrl("../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")%>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveUrl("../Scripts/jquery.tooltip.js")%>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveUrl("../Scripts/GeneralNEEV.js")%>'></script>


            <asp:Repeater ID="rcClinics" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rcClinics_ItemDataBound" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div id="menu" runat="server"  class='FirstMenu'>
                        <div>
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="45%" style="font-size:13px !important;">
                                            <span>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblCli" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="55%" style="font-size:14px !important;">
                                            <span id="spVac" runat="server">0</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

And the code behind file is

```
namespace Tree.Templates.DynamicContent.Vpo.UserControls
{
    public partial class ViewClinic : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public VpoParameters VpoParas { get; set; }
        private JArray AllClinics = new JArray();
        private List<Clinic> clinics;
        private List<CareUnit> careUnits;
        private List<Total> total;
        private int intClinicId = 0;
        private int satellite_patient = 0;
        private int id = 0;
        protected String VpoEditUpdateUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VpoEditUpdateUrl"];
        protected List<ColumnInfo> cinfo = new List<ColumnInfo>();
        protected String user = "";
        CareUnit ava = new CareUnit();
        protected int avCuId = 0;
}
```

Thanks and regards
Utpal

Comment: Can you supply the code from the ascx file and the namespace and class declaration lines from the code behind file. This will help give an accurate answer

Comment: @matt_lethargic I have modified the post and given the code

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the backup folder in visual studio and selecting exclude from project and rebuild. If there are .cs files with the same namespaces and class names then they'll clash. As your classes are partial it'll try and compile your backup folder and prob fail